# Issue with Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id serial primary key not null,
  name varchar(320),
  description varchar(200),
  price numeric(10,2),
  type varchar(20),
  imageurl text
);
```

And am trying to insert into products this:

```
INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, type, imageurl)
VALUES (‘Xbox One S’, ‘500GB System plus Halo 5’, 299.99, ‘xbox’, ‘http://www.gamestop.com/common/images/lbox/127716b2.jpg’);
```

but I keep getting this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "One"

I'm not sure why, it looks correct to me. Anyone know why I am getting the error?

Comment: You have curly quotes instead of single quotes.  You just need to fix the quotes.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know there was a difference.

Comment: Use `'` not `‘`

Comment: It's easier if you use a proper text editor to write, not a word processor, btw.